# How can I calculate average scores from these entries in django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-forms

So I have this model:

```
class scoreShow(models.Model):
    dancer = models.ForeignKey(dancer)
    s1 = models.IntegerField(max_length = 2)
    s2 = models.IntegerField(max_length = 2)
    s3 = models.IntegerField(max_length = 2)
    s4 = models.IntegerField(max_length = 2)
    s5 = models.IntegerField(max_length = 2)
    s6 = models.IntegerField(max_length = 2)
    s7 = models.IntegerField(max_length = 2)
    counter = models.IntegerField(max_length = 2)
    stotal = models.IntegerField(max_length = 3)
    field_1 = models.IntegerField(max_length = 20, null=True, blank=True)
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length = 20, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.dancer)
```

Which is fed information from this view form:

```
def scores(request):
     perf = dancer.objects.filter(perform=True)

     if request.method =='POST':
        intpk = request.POST.get("form")
        whendone = request.POST.get("done")

        contestant =dancer.objects.get(pk=intpk)

        showcase = inlineformset_factory(dancer, scoreShow, extra = 1)
        form = showcase(instance=None)

        if whendone == "save":

            form = showcase(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=contestant)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()

     return render_to_response("scores.html",locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

It accepts numeric values from 1 to 10 from about 13 people. I need to calculate the average of the scores that the 13 people put in. 2 averages:

1. The average of the 7 categories ex. average of s1, average of s2 &
2. The average of all of the S's added together so average of s1 total+ s2 total ... divided by total entries. T

I would also like to avoid having anyone submit a score twice if thats possible. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [Aggregation feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) by calling:

   ```
   from django.db.models import Avg
   qs = ScoreShow.objects.all()
   return qs.aggregate(Avg('s1'), Avg('s2'), Avg('s3'), Avg('s4'), Avg('s5'), Avg('s6'),Avg('s7'))
   ```

   or a little shorter:

   ```
   qs = ScoreShow.objects.all()
   return qs.aggregate(*[Avg('s%d' % i) for i in range(1, 8)])
   ```
2. To calculate average value of all scores together you need to combine aggregate with [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

   ```
   from django.db.models import Avg, Sum
   fields = ['s%d' % i for i in range(1,8)]
   qs = ScoreShow.objects.annotate(sAll=Sum('id', field='+'.join(fields))).all()
   return qs.aggregate(Avg('sAll'))
   ```
3. To make sure that nobody submits two scores add `unique=True` to dancer foreign key:

   ```
   class ScoreShow(models.Model):
       dancer = models.ForeignKey(dancer, unique=True)
   ```

Comment: Wow thanks, the first part works fine however for the total average I keep getting this error : Sum' object has no attribute 'all', i tried it with filter and i also got that error as well, any thoughts? and again thank you

Comment: My mistake, I forgot one closing bracket.